Is there a way to round out lines for Polarchart?
Is there a way to round of datapoint for the polarchart, like how its done in the d3 package:

Or is there someway we could work around and make this possible?
Cheers!

Unfortunately there isn’t a direct built-in option to round out the lines of radar chart.
Still to get the curved appearance of the lines you can preprocess your data to include additional points that creates the curved effect between original points.
Demo(change the number you iterate interpolatePoints function to see difference): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9d01hk3y/
function smoothenData(data, count) {
 let smoothedData = data;
 for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  smoothedData = interpolatePoints(smoothedData);
 }

 return smoothedData;
}

const smoothedData = smoothenData(data, 1)
